# Can't read some characters from UTF-8 file. Pure C

Tags: c, encoding, utf-8

I know, there are several similar topics on stackoverflow, but i haven't found a solution for my problem.
I try to read UTF-8 file. Everything is okay with english letters, but I can't read russian or spanish letters.
Here is my code. Just example.

```
FILE * fp;
char line[3];
fp = fopen("letters.data", "r");
if (fp == NULL)
    return;
int i=0;

fread(line,1,3, fp); // BOM
wint_t w;
while( w = fgetwc(fp) )
{
    wprintf(L"%c", w);
}
fclose(fp);
```

Here is `letters.data` file:

[image]

And output data:

[image]

I don't know what to do.

Comment: Maybe you should use `setlocale`.

Comment: The format specifier `%c` outputs a `char`, not a `wchar`. Use `%lc` to output a `wchar`.

Comment: @LeonardMichlmayr tried to write `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "")`. It didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fgetwc()` returns a `wchar` (a "wide character"). That's not the same thing as UTF-8. A `wchar` is some fixed size (often 16 bits). UTF-8 characters are variable length between one and four bytes long and require some special parsing. For very simple work, [Reading Unicode (UTF-8) in C](http://zaemis.blogspot.com/2011/06/reading-unicode-utf-8-by-hand-in-c.html) is useful. If you need more complex work, then see [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/home).

Note that you're assuming a BOM at the start. UTF-8 files should not have a BOM, though some Windows editors add one anyway. You should be careful of this issue.

If all you're doing is reading from one stream and writing to another, there's no need of course to worry about UTF-8. You can just treat them as raw bytes. But if you're going to interpret them, then you're going to need to decode the UTF-8 correctly.

That said, you should also verify that you really do have a UTF-8 file. For example, on Windows it is pretty common for files to be written in various code pages or UTF-16 (UTF-16 is the kind of file that is supposed to have a BOM). I almost always find it useful to look at the file in a hex editor to make sure that the bytes are what you think they are.

Comment: Actully, the code from the link you mentioned above also doesn't work. It gives the same results: English - okay, Russian, Spanish - not okay.

Comment: Did you check the hex output of the data? Is it really UTF-8?

Comment: not sure i understand how to do this. I just created file(on windows)  and saved it with UTF-8(user can choose: unicode, ascii, utf-8).